# How do I check if the current page is a blog post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I'm developing a custom theme for my website and I can't seem to check if the current page is a blog post or a page. How would I do this?

My code so far (post.php):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
    <div class="hero">
        <h1>hello world</h1>
    </div>
<? elseif (is_page()) : ?>
    <div class="hero">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
<? elseif (is_singular()) : ?>
    <div class="hero">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p>Date: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
        <p>Categories:</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress helper function [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) checks if the current request "is for an existing single post of any post type".

```php
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    // request is for a single post.
}
```

```php
if ( is_singular( 'page' ) ) {
    // Request is for a single page.
}
```

There are additional helper functions, like [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) and [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) that vary slightly from `is_singular()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use something like this....

```
<?php
  get_header(); 
  if(get_post()->post_type === 'page') { 
?>

<div class="hero">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
</div>
<? 
  }elseif (get_post()->post_type === 'post') { 
?>
<div class="hero">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
 <? 
   }else (is_singular()) { 
 ?>
<div class="hero">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p>Date: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
    <p>Categories:</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hopefully this one can help you...